# Detect touch in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am trying to make the navigation bar disappear when the user touches in the Search Bar, just like in Contacts. Please take a look at the image I have placed below.

How do you detect a touch in the search bar?

[image]

Comment: By using the seachbarcontroller instead of searchbar object from IB the delegates get fired and the view will scroll over the nav bar automatically. If you want to hard code it you need to take a look at uisearchbarcontroller class reference...here is the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarSearchButtonClicked%3a) and [(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing%3a) to implement your logic.

Comment: Hi. I used the (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar and it worked! Thanks a lot.